# Can't open specified folder android R

Tags: java, android

Hi everyone i know in android R i cant open folder in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ section so i created a folder in /storage/emulated/0/Document/myapp to save images from my app (screenshot) however i tried the following ways still can't open this folder:

```
fun openDirectory() {
        val dir: File
        // Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
            if (Build.VERSION_CODES.R > SDK_INT) {
                dir = File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path
                            + "//CHAN"
                )
            } else {
                dir = File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
                        .path
                            + "//CHAN"
                )
            }
            val pickerInitialUri = Uri.parse(dir.toString())
            putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
        }

        startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
```

```
fun openFile() {
        val dir: File
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            type = "file/*"

            if (Build.VERSION_CODES.R > SDK_INT) {
                dir = File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path
                            + "//CHAN"
                )
            } else {
                dir = File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
                        .path
                            + "//CHAN"
                )
            }
            val pickerInitialUri = Uri.parse(dir.toString())
            putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
        }

        startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
```

```
open fun openFolder(): Unit {
    val location : String  = "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/CHAN/"
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    val mydir = Uri.parse("$location")
    intent.setDataAndType(mydir, "application/*") // or use */*
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

I create folder with code:

```
        final File dir;
        if (Build.VERSION_CODES.R > Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
            dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                    + "//CHAN");
        } else {
            dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getPath()
                    + "//CHAN");
        }
```

My app :`minSdkVersion 29`,`targetSdkVersion 30`
I have a permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE However i can't permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
Is there any way to open a folder automatically? Or Is there a better way to save and view these photos? Thank you.

Comment: You can let the user choose that directory using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. Further you posted much too much code for picking a directory.

Comment: Further on Android 11 you can just list the files in that directory using File.listFiles(). Well if the fikes belong to your app.

Comment: @blackapps I want when the user presses the application button to automatically open the specified folder. Is this reasonable? Thank you

Comment: What is an application button?

Comment: @blackapps oh sorry,I mean a button in my app

Comment: What about it?? Please describe what you want to the point. I think your button is irrelevant.

Comment: @blackapps My point can be summed up like this: in my application I press an "open" button which will immediately open a folder that I have already selected(/storage/emulated/0/Document/myapp).

Comment: and i also want to know how to create a folder of me in /storage/emulated/0/myapp. it seems in android 11 this is forbidden right?

Comment: Pretty unclear as what would you use trying to open in general? Do you want the user to select a folder?

Comment: No .I mean it's automatic. Sorry for my english

Comment: Then i have no idea what you mean with 'open a folder'. Would there be anything the user would see? Or what should happen?

Comment: @blackapps it contains image (screenshoot from my app). the user will view it

Comment: What is there suddenly that the user can see your images? How would that be possible? Please come to the point.

Comment: For example, my application will take a screenshot and save the image if it detects a face in the image after users will access those images in a specified folder with the click of a button from the app. I don't know if such approach makes sense or is there any other way to do this? Thank you

Comment: Yes that makes sense. But nothing for nothing. What do you wanna use?

Comment: @blackapps I don't understand what you mean. can this be done?

Comment: I do not exactly understand what you want. So that is why i'm asking and asking... But you do not come to the point is my impression. Sorry.

Comment: oh sorry @blackapps ,maybe I should be fine with the current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put in a  intent where Your_Request_Code is, like 42? Thats what others seem to be using
This also needs to be on Activity Result

```
if (_requestCode == 42 && _resultCode ==
Activity.RESULT_OK) {
Uri uri = null;
if (_data != null) {
uri = _data.getData();
ur = uri.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

EXTRA_INITIAL_URI should specify a document URI or a tree URI with document ID.

Example:

```
// Directories : Pictures , Music , Movies

val documentUri= Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3APictures%2FmyApp%2F")
```

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        intent.type = "*/*"
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            intent.putExtra(
                DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI,
                documentUri
            )
        }

startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE)
```